# Why is the this mongodb query slow when it's indexed?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Why is the following query slow when an index is being utilized?

```
db.foo.count({$and:[{'metadata.source':'WZ'}, {'metadata.source':'ED'}]})
```

with the index

```
{
  "v" : 1,
  "key" : { 'metadata.source" : 1 },
  "name" : "metadata.source_1",
  "ns" : "bar.foo"
}
```

where the metadata field is a JSON Array

The following with a single value returns immediately

```
db.foo.count({'metadata.source':'WZ'})
```

**Update:**

I'm using Mongo v3.0.3. Setup is a sharded replica-set with about 12M documents.

I tried the following with the same delay

```
db.foo.count({'metadata.source' : { $all : ['WZ', 'ED'] }})
```

When I check db.currentOp(), it shows the following which seems correct:

```
"planSummary" : "IXSCAN { metadata.source: 1.0 }"
```

But the numYields is very high and continues to increase. Does this mean the index does not fit into memory and is reading from disk. There should be plenty of memory based on my db.foo.stats(). Anything else I should look for to help diagnose?

This is also using the wiredTiger storage engine which seems to have some noted performance issues. I'm attempting to upgrade to 3.0.7 to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Do you mean that it's slower without an index?

Comment: I just mean seems to run forever. A count on a single value come back immediately, such as db.foo.count({'metadata.source':'WZ'}).

Comment: @MikeWagner, is it normal that you're missing curly braces on the first query in the `and`? If I'm not mistaken, it should be `db.foo.count({$and:[{'metadata.source':'WZ'}, {'metadata.source':'ED'}]})`

Comment: Actually I have it...It's on another network and I didn't type it correctly. I'll update the post

Comment: @MikeWagner Also include the fact that it runs much quicker when you do not have the `and` condition in your question. This is a relevant fact that will help others diagnose your problem.

Comment: please post which version of MongoDB you are using.  In the latest (3.0+) there should be no difference between $in and $and.   And please post explain output for equivalent find query - that will show you exactly how/which index is or is not being used.

Comment: @Philipp Actually, `$in` is more of an `$or` shortcut. This would be an [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#op._S_all), as in `db.foo.count({'metadata.source': {$all: ['WZ','ED']}})`. Can you try that, Mike?